# vue render string as a already existing component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, jsx

I am trying to build a vue app that receives from the database some html as string just like the following example:

```
<b-field :label="field.nome" :message="field.message"><b-input :value="value" :type="field.type" :maxlength="field.maxlength" :expanded="true" v-model="inputValue"/></b-field>
```

So, as you can see, it may contains components, like the b-field from buefy.
My question is, can I render this string as the actual buefy component and its behavior?
It doesn't matter if it's in the template tag or via render function with JSX, I just want to know if I can do it and how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the [runtime + compiler version](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only) of vue, then you can create components on the fly:

```
const vm = Vue({
  template: "<b-field :label=...",
  data: ()=> ({
    field: {nome: ...}
  })
})
```

Which you can mount onto an element.

```
<span ref="placeholder"/>

vm.$mount(this.$refs.placeholder)
this.$on('$destroy', ()=> vm.$destroy())
```

**Or**, if you've got multiple dynamic components:

```
<span ref="container"/>

vm.$mount()
this.$refs.container.appendChild(vm.$el)
this.$on('$destroy', ()=> vm.$destroy())
```

Comment: Bob, your answer helped me. But I got 2 problems. A) It's rendering only the first element, I want to loop through an array and render every element it gives me. B) It is rendering the value as an object, the input writes "[Object] [Object]" instead the real value, even if the value was simple string or number

Comment: That was not clear in the original question, i've updated my answer to account for multiple components. Create a new SO question for the "[Object] [Object]" issue , as this question doesn't provide enough details to answer what's going wrong.

Comment: I don't know why, but changing the code to .container.appendChild, the input rendered the right value instead of "[Object] [Object]".